# remove lines link two scatter points

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, scatter-plot

Anyone please help me how to remove the lines link scatter points when plot with graph objects from Python
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BpWp.png)

```
`
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x[65000:133083], y=y[65000:133083], z=z[65000:133083], marker=dict(
    size=1, # Changed node size...
    color=color[65000:133083], # ...and color
    colorscale='Viridis',
    line=None,
    showscale=True)))`
```

Please help me solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add:

```py
mode='markers',
marker=dict(
        size=12,
#       color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
```

Though i'm not sure why you do have lines given your code...

Comment: Thanks Mat, the lines were there because I didn't put the mode = 'markers'.